# Maven: how to update version of one module in a multi-module project?

Tags: java, maven

I have three projects: `jar1, jar2, war`

Dependencies: `war --> jar2 --> jar1`

All projects are at `1.0.0.0` release. Now for the next release, a file in `jar2` is updated and hence only its version needs to change to `1.0.0.1`. (The release version of `war` will also need to change, but that's the next step. The important thing here is jar1` version is not updated.)

Is there a good maven plugin or another tool to update the release version of `jar2` to `1.0.0.1` and also update the dependency in `war` on `jar2` to the same version?

I tried `versions:set` with `-DartifactId`, but it sets the version for all modules.

Comment: do you have a pom.xml ?

Comment: @JordiCastilla yes, standard poms for all projects.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075382/release-modules-w-different-version-of-multimodule-maven-project-through-jenkin

Comment: At the place where I work we looked at the same problem. You can use the release plugin to make the first task (to update the release version of jar2 to 1.0.0.1). To my best knowledge there is no good tooling for the second task (update the dependency in war on jar2). We also looked at different goals of the version plugin but it did not work for us.

Comment: @Michal what did you finally do?

Comment: Well, actually we have written a bash script which handles both tasks for us. Of course, this is less then ideal as the poms have to follow given structure - yeah, I know bash/awk/sed are no XML parsing tools - but it works for us. However, I still think for the first task the 'mvn release:prepare' inside the project folder to be changed/released shall work for you.  For the second one I would go for manually editing the poms, unless you have really huge number of dependent projects.

Answer (score 1):

Each of your 3 modules (jar1, jar2 and war) have its own pom.xml file where you can find the following tags

```
<project>
    ...
    <groupId>my.company.team</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.application</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    ...
</project>
```

After you made changes within your project, you have
raise the version number and deploy it again. (see [Maven lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html))

*NOTE: that you need to change the version to a new one if you want to deploy a new project state to your maven repository except your version number ends with -SNAPSHOT.

In other projects which aren't using the newest version you could correct the version number within the dependency to the newest version on the maven-repository you are using (check your .m2/settings.xml file if you want to change your default maven-repository).

To automate the release process for new project versions you could use the [release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) from maven.

Comment: Well, i am aware of all these. My question was specific to a plugin/tool which will let me increment the version only for one module within multi-module project. How is this done with `release-plugin`?

Comment: Thanks for downgrading. In the documentation of the release-plugin and the examples to it is a description about that: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html

Comment: In the link, step 3 "Change the version in the POMs from x-SNAPSHOT to a new version (you will be prompted for the versions to use)". This increments the version for all POMs, irrespective of whether the files associated with that pom's project are modified not. This is what we are trying to avoid. Why should the pom version be updated if the files have not changed? The question is how to update version of only specific pom.